# let $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are topologies on $X$ and $\tau_1 \subseteq\tau_2$ . when $\tau_1 =\tau_2$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

let $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$  are topologies on $X$ and $\tau_1 \subseteq\tau_2$ . when $\tau_1 =\tau_2$ ?

1- every convergent seqence in $(X,\tau_2)$ is  convergent seqence in $(X,\tau_1)$.

2-$(X,\tau_1)$ be Hausdorff and $(X,\tau_2)$  be compact .

3-every  compact set in $(X,\tau_2)$ is  also  compact set in$(X,\tau_1)$.

4-$(X,\tau_2)$ be Hausdorff and $(X,\tau_1)$  be compact .

> let $X=[0,1]$ with $\tau_1$ be euclidean topology and $\tau_2$ be discrete topology so  $\tau_1 \subseteq\tau_2$ now "1","2"and "4" are false. so 2 is true ?

Comment: Why is 3 false in your example?  Compact sets in the discrete topology would be finite, therefore compact in the Euclidean topology.

Comment: @Randall .  We can't use my example for  "2" so "2" is answer ? But my example is countexample for 1,3 and 4 so 2 is answer?

Comment: I don’t even know what the question is.

Comment: @Randall .i want proof "2" and i can show this as follow.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is a counterexample for 1, 3 and 4.

$(X, \tau_2)$ is not compact so it doesn't work for 2.

So 2 must be the answer by elimination. Now reason why that is true.

Answer (score 1):

"2" is true .

Consider the identity map $Id : (X,\tau_2) \rightarrow (X,\tau_1)$. Since $\tau_1 \subset \tau_2$, this map is continuous. Also, a continuous map from a compact to a Hausdorff space is a closed.